Check if input .csv is valid before using \pgfplotstableread
I use pgfplotstable to read in external .csv data and print them in a formatted (MWE is unformatted) way.
The issue is, that the input .csv is not completely under my control. This means, it could be, that the input data are corrupted. A typically example would be, that the row length is unequal within these data.
So my question is, is there a way to test such a scenario?
MWE
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% This example if fine
\begin{filecontents}{data1.csv}
    A;B;C  
    D;E;F 
    G;H;I 
\end{filecontents}

% This example is wrong
\begin{filecontents}{data2.csv}
    A,B;C  % => "," instead of a ";"
    D;E;F 
    G;H;I 
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\checkInutData}[1]{
    % If input data is fine, do
        \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{#1}{\csvdata}
        \pgfplotstableset{verb string type}
        \pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
    % Else
        % Print, that input data are incorrect
}

\begin{document}
    % This works!
    \checkInutData{data1.csv}\\\\
    % This should print an error
    %\checkInutData{data2.csv}      
\end{document}


in your other question, you already showed how to count the items, so you could e.g. count them and compare with whatever the number should be.

@cfr But the problem occurs while read in the data. So I have no chance to test anything.

You could consider doing the check outside of LaTeX before you start, for example with awk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050427/checking-that-the-rows-in-a-file-have-the-same-number-of-columns. With a little bit of trouble you could also call such a oneliner from within your LaTeX code and proceed based on the return value, but it is easier to make sure the file is ok before you run LaTeX.

@Marijn Yes in general you are completely right. But there will be situations, where I can't ensure the correctness of these data. The code is compiled within a CI/CD environment. So I don't have immediately access to this machine. Of course I could also bring up some services in the CI/CD to check this correctness, but this will make it even more complicated. I have requested a feature request to \pgfplotstable to just get a return value if the import was successful or not. I think this could be helpful also for others.
